# "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied" _winreg.DeleteKey

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I am running a small chunk of code to auto-delete profiles from Windows PCs. Determining the usernames and deleting the folders works great, but I can't seem to get the reg keys deleted. I am running the .py in an elevated command prompt and I can't seem to find an answer that works. Bare in mind I'm pretty new to this. Thanks in advance!
"dirs" is a list of usernames to be deleted.

```
#Determines OS, finds the SID, and makes it a string, then deletes the key
keyloc = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
if opersys == "8":
    for kilist in dirs:
        sid = win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid(win32security.LookupAccountName(None, kilist)[0])
        key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyloc, 0, _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        _winreg.DeleteKey(key, sid)
```

Comment: What Windows OS is it? Is the UAC disabled. Usually this error comes if you don't have enough privilege to perform the action.

Comment: Can you access the registry with regedit?

Comment: Win8.1, UAC is enabled. I can do the deletion manually, and am an administrator on the asset.

Comment: I can indeed access the registry with regedit, modify and delete keys as I please. I thought I got around UAC by running the command in the Administrator Command Prompt?

Comment: UAC does not give you `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, even for an Administrator.

Comment: My understanding is that it is giving itself full access using KEY_ALL_ACCESS? The error quotes _winreg.DeleteKey(key, sid) as being the offending line.

Comment: Try `DELETE` rather than `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`

Comment: You probably need more rights than an admin has

Comment: There isn't a '_winreg.DELETE'? @cdarke

Comment: It's not specific to `_winreg`, it's a general WIN32 permissions.

Comment: If the handle was opened successfully with `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` (0xF003F), then for sure it has `DELETE` (bit 16) access. But that doesn't mean the subkey `sid` allows the delete.